# Как задать имя скачиваему файлу на JavaScript c помощью data url

Tags: javascript

В целом я сделал так

```
window.open("data:application/octet-stream," + (JSON.stringify(content)), "fail");
```

Теперь возник вопрос, как задать имя файлу.

Answer (score 1):

`<a download='FileName' href='your_url'>`, но не для всех браузеров (http://caniuse.com/#feat=download). `your_url` может быть и Data URI как у вас.

Чтобы автоматически это дело скачать, думаю, нужно просто создать невидимую ссылку и сделать по ней jQuery.click().

Comment: Скачивается оно нормально, мне имя задать ему нужно. Назвать там file.txt к примеру и чтобы оно с таким названием скачалось

Comment: Какая часть фразы "FileName" вам не понятна? `<a download='File.txt' href='your_url'>`, например?

Comment: Я так понимаю в Сафари и ИЕ оно не работает, и как бы хотелось узнать как задать имя файла в window.open