# Сохранение данных с помощью JQUERY в xls

Tags: html, jquery, excel, xls

Нашел код который сохраняет данные из таблицы в xls

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
      template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
      base64 = function(s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
      },
      format = function(s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
          return c[p];
        })
      }
    return function(table, name) {
      if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
      var ctx = {
        worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
        table: table.innerHTML
      }
      window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
  })() < /script>
```

Сохраняет,все хорошо.Но есть два важных вопроса:

1)При сохранении файла он сохраняется как скачанные файлы.xls.Как можно пометь это имя?я не смог понять(

2)При открытии в Excel выдавает такое(но все хорошо отображается)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Уже обсуждалось, ищите решения тут: [Как задать имя скачиваему файлу на JavaScript c помощью data url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435444/)
2. Потому что расширение должно быть `.xlsx` (XML-образный формат, который используется у вас), а не `.xls` (бинарный формат, который давно устарел).

Нужно заменить одну строчку:

> `var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',`

на:

> `var uri = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,',`

Вот, кстати, полный список типов для разных офисных файлов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/

Comment: первое пофиксил.а как разобраться со вторым?как сделать чтобы этого не было?

Comment: Поправил свой ответ, смотрите, отмечайте как правильный.

Comment: Ради прикола можно просто в строку браузера вставить текст `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,` :)